# Minimize sum of squares function, then extract variance-covariance

Tags: r

In brief my problem concentrated in extracting **variance-covariance matrix** from minimized sum of squares function. Below is a simple example of what I try to **minimize**.

---

Given:

```
p <- c(7.8, 4.1, 6.2, 5.3, 10.1, 9.6)
x <- 1:6
f <- function(x,q){x^2-q*x+14}
```

sum of squared errors of prediction

```
SSE <- function(q){ sum((p-f(x,q))^2) }
```

---

Minimizing example then calculating variance covariance matrix is the main point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you minimize?

Comment: How to minimize above example in additional to extract variance covariance matrix to obtain standard error of the parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your model is linear you can use `lm`:

```
p <- c(7.8, 4.1, 6.2, 5.3, 10.1, 9.6)
x <- 1:6
f <- function(x,q){x^2-q*x+14}

fit <- lm(I(p - x^2 - 14) ~ x + 0)
summary(fit)$coef
#   Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#x -6.275824   0.212917 -29.47545 8.426765e-07
vcov(fit)
#           x
#x 0.04533366

#illustrate that this is the minimum
f <- function(x,q){x^2-q*x+14}
SSE <- function(q){ sum((p-f(x,q))^2) }

a <- seq(from = 0, to =10, by = 0.001)
plot(a, sapply(a, SSE), type = "l")
abline(v = -coef(fit))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks Mr. Roland for your answer, if you don't mind what if I have non linear model and more than one parameter which package can be used in that case?

Comment: There are numerous possibilities but usually you'd use `nls`.

Comment: Many thanks Mr. Roland